# Javascript onchange with select element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a dropdown menu and when one option is selected a div appears. All the divs are set to display none, When one option is clicked I would like to change that style to display: block. So far I have used onchange but that only applies to the whole select element and not the specific options.

So what are my choices for changing the display to block when clicking on a certain option of a select element?

This is my code

```
#card1, #card2, #card3 {
    display: none;
  }
<select name="" id="" onchange="showOnChange()">
  <option value="card1">card1</option>
  <option value="card2">card2</option>
  <option value="card3">card3</option>
</select>
<div id="card1">card1</div>
<div id="card2">card2</div>
<div id="card3">card3</div>

<script>
  function showOnChange() {
    document.getElementById('card1').style.display = "block";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: "but that only applies to the whole select element and not the specific options" The <select> is considered changed if it has a selected index (option) changed. Not clear what your problem is.

Comment: Consider toggling between "none" and "" (empty string) rather than "block" so that the element adopts its default or inherited style and you don't need to know what that is (and it can be set independently through CSS or other means).

Answer (score 1):

I little bit updated your html and js function as well, see below please if work for you:

```
<select name="" id="" onChange="showOnChange(this)">
  <option value="card1">card1</option>
  <option value="card2">card2</option>
  <option value="card3">card3</option>
</select>
```

And JS part:

```
function showOnChange(self) {
    var allDiv = self.options;
    for(var i = 0; i < allDiv.length; i++){
        document.getElementById(allDiv[i].value).style.display = "none";
    }
    document.getElementById(self.value).style.display = 'block';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass the value of select in showOnChange function or you can get in the function as well

```js
  function showOnChange(val) {
    document.getElementById(val).style.display = "block";
  }
```

```css
#card1, #card2, #card3 {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<select name="" id="" onchange="showOnChange(this.value)">
  <option value="card1">card1</option>
  <option value="card2">card2</option>
  <option value="card3">card3</option>
</select>

<div id="card1">card1</div>
<div id="card2">card2</div>
<div id="card3">card3</div>
```

Comment: When navigating with the keyboard, a *change* event is dispatched for each press of the keyboard so that all visited divs are displayed even if only the last is selected.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the value from the card that you select and show that id

```
#card1, #card2, #card3 {
    display: none;
  }
<select name="" id="" onchange="showOnChange(this)">
  <option value="card1">card1</option>
  <option value="card2">card2</option>
  <option value="card3">card3</option>
</select>
<div id="card1">card1</div>
<div id="card2">card2</div>
<div id="card3">card3</div>

<script>
  function showOnChange(element) {
    var value = element.value
    document.getElementById(value).style.display = "block";
  }
</script>
```

*Note the this keyword added to the select onchange function*

Answer (score 0):

You can catch which option is selected in your onChange and then based on that you can show your div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
  #card1{
    display:block;
  }
  #card2, #card3 {
    display: none;
  }
  </style>
<select name="" id="slct" onchange="showOnChange(event)">
  <option value="card1">card1</option>
  <option value="card2">card2</option>
  <option value="card3">card3</option>
</select>
<div id="card1">card1</div>
<div id="card2">card2</div>
<div id="card3">card3</div>

<script>
  function showOnChange(e) {
    var elem = document.getElementById("slct");
    var value = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value;
    if(value == "card1")
      {
        document.getElementById('card1').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('card2').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('card3').style.display = "none";
      }
   else if(value == "card2")
     {
          document.getElementById('card1').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('card2').style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById('card3').style.display = "none";
     }
   else if(value == "card3")
     {
        document.getElementById('card1').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('card2').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('card3').style.display = "block";
     }

  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please check below link for the jsbin

https://jsbin.com/memilufogi/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

You could give all your divs a class, so that you can query the DOM by that class and hide them all. Then you look for the div whose ID matches the selected option and show it.

See the attached snippets.

```js
document.getElementById('cardMenu').addEventListener('change', showOnChange);

function showOnChange(evt) {
  // capture the target of the change event : select element
  var cardMenu = evt.target;

  // hide all cards
  var cards = document.getElementsByClassName('card');
  for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    cards[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // show the card whose id matches the selected value
  document.getElementById(cardMenu.value).style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#card1,
#card2,
#card3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select name="cardMenu" id="cardMenu">
        <option value="card1">card1</option>
        <option value="card2">card2</option>
        <option value="card3">card3</option>
    </select>

<div class="card" id="card1">card1</div>
<div class="card" id="card2">card2</div>
<div class="card" id="card3">card3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
<style>
   #card1, #card2, #card3 {
   display: none;
   }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- Pass current selected value -->
<select name="" id="" onchange="showOnChange(this.value)">
  <option value="card1">card1</option>
  <option value="card2">card2</option>
  <option value="card3">card3</option>
</select>
<!-- Add common class in every property -->
<!-- Class will help to reset all class display none when selected new option -->
<div id="card1" class="div_cls">card1</div>
<div id="card2" class="div_cls">card2</div>
<div id="card3" class="div_cls">card3</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
  function showOnChange(div_id) {
    var div_id = div_id;
   /*
     Getting lenght of all div
   */
    var div_len = document.getElementsByClassName("div_cls").length;
    /* run loop and reset all div display to none*/
    for(i=0; i< div_len; i++) {
      document.getElementsByClassName("div_cls")[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    // Now set block for current selected option
    document.getElementById(div_id).style.display = "block";
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just with javascript:

```js
function showOnChange() {
  var whichOp = document.getElementById("sel").selectedIndex;
  var c = document.getElementsByClassName("card");
  for (len = 0;len < c.length; len++)
    c[len].style.display = "none";
  c[whichOp].style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#card1, #card2, #card3 {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<select name="" id="sel" onchange="showOnChange()">
  <option value="card1">card1</option>
  <option value="card2">card2</option>
  <option value="card3">card3</option>
</select>
<div id="card1" class="card">card1</div>
<div id="card2" class="card">card2</div>
<div id="card3" class="card">card3</div>
```